# Account Google Developer Console deleted - Lost my project

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have a huge issue... 
I had a project defined on a Google Developer Console account in order to use GCM. 
Unfortunately, the administrator of my company google apps account deleted this account so I lost access to the console to manager the project!

I cannot modify my app which used GCM because it is signed by Samsung so I cannot just create a new project and change SENDER_ID on the app...

Is there any solution ? for example to migrate the project to another account !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You may refer to this [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) if you want your account to be transferred from the previous one to the current one. It is stated that both accounts should be active in order to recover the apps or project.